# Response from $.getJSON returns null

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax, json

I want to call a server side method using Jquery getJSON with .NET 3.5, MVC2 and JQuery1.4.1.

I've followed some online tutorials, but cannot get the serverside method to return anything other than null. All 3 alerts are fired in the JS below, and I can hit a break point on my server side method (also below). As I'm starting out, I've included all the client side code just in case I have done something stupid. Any idea what I am doing wrong - I've spent ages trying to get a value back from the server. Many thanks.

My client code is: (Each line is missing the beginning <)

```
<@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    Home Page
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">    

<form id="form1" runat="server">    
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="True">
</asp:ScriptManager>   

<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>   

<script>
function test() 
{
  alert("Here");  
  $.getJSON(
    "/Home/Test", null, function(data, status) { alert("Success!"); alert(data); });
};      
</script>

<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Call Page Methods" OnClientClick="return test()"/> 

</form>        

</asp:Content>
```

And my server side code is:

```
public JsonResult Test()
{
  string fooString = "test";
  return Json(fooString, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are mixing some notions here. ASP.NET and ASP.NET MVC is not the same thing. From your code snippet I assume this is an ASP.NET MVC application (your view inherits from `System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage`). In ASP.NET MVC application `<asp:Button runat="server"` and `<form runat="server">` and `<asp:ScriptManager` are no longer used, you can forget about those and there are no page methods, there are controllers and actions.

So you could do the following in your view:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">    

    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>   
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $('#btnTest').click(function() {
        $.getJSON('/Home/Test', null, function(data) { 
            alert("Success!");
        });
        return false;
    });
    </script>
    <input type="button" id="btnTest" name="test" />
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: There are several WebForms controls that do work in MVC, like the Repeater, Menu, and Button.  Not that it's a great idea, but it's not invalid or going to cause an error.

Comment: @Dave Ward, they do work but I wouldn't recommend their usage.

Comment: That's great - thanks Darin. I was definitely getting confused with what can and can't be used with MVC. I don't think I would have ever worked out that I couldn't have a ScriptManager. Lesson learnt. The return from the JSON request is working properly now. Thanks again.